# How to remove lines in NPP?

Tags: notepad++

I have text like this :

```
Number,Name,IDclient,Workhours
```

and I need to remove the first 3, and leave only the `Workhours`.

How can I do that in NPP?

Answer (score 0):

Do a replace, finding:

```
^([^,]*,){3}([^,]*)$
```

And replace with:

```
\2
```

Make sure you are using the 'Regular express' is checked (see below).

Note: Number, Name and IDclient cannot have a comma in them and no line breaks.  This group the first the fields (comma delimited) as group 1, and the 4th as group 2, replacing is with group 2.